# Particle system to individual objects with keyframes

Tags: particles, physics

i have this animation where the particles move from the bottom to the top and i want to delete all the particles that don't make it to the top, how can i do that?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesh with Collision Physic can kill particles. Add a particle killer mesh and turn of it's render visibility.

[image]